# Laravel 5.0 Eloquent relationship issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have Tournament, 
Inside a tournament, I have Categories
For each categories, I have CategoriesSettings

I defined a relationship in the Category Model :

```
 public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\CategorySettings');
}
```

So, I can access $tournament->categories without any problem ( with a belongsToMany rel. in Tournament model )

I have 3 tables:

Tournaments, Categories, category_tournament, and CategoriesSettings

category_tournament is just a pivot table.

But when I try to loop on categories, and try to reach settings in the view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->settings}}
@endforeach
```

I just get the result for the first category.

Then the result is an array, and I expect a CategorySettings Object.

The funny stuff is when I dd $categories, I have a collection of 6 Categories, but then, when I check the category object, I can't find my hasOne Relationship:

```
 0 => Category {#437 ▼
  #table: "category"
  +timestamps: true
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "pivot" => Pivot {#436 ▼
      #parent: Tournament {#426 ▶}
      #foreignKey: "tournament_id"
      #otherKey: "category_id"
      #guarded: []
      #connection: null
      #table: "category_tournament"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:4 [▶]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
```

I just find my pivot relation

Here is the query that is ran with :

```
$tournament->categories
```

.

```
SELECT 
`ken_category`.*,
`ken_category_tournament`.`tournament_id` AS `pivot_tournament_id`,
`ken_category_tournament`.`category_id` AS `pivot_category_id`,
`ken_category_tournament`.`created_at` AS `pivot_created_at`,
`ken_category_tournament`.`updated_at` AS `pivot_updated_at`
FROM
`ken_category`
    INNER JOIN
`ken_category_tournament` ON `ken_category`.`id` =     `ken_category_tournament`.`category_id`
WHERE
`ken_category_tournament`.`tournament_id` = ?
```

and the final query:

```
$category->settings


select * from `ken_category_settings` 
where `ken_category_settings`.`category_id` = ? 
and `ken_category_settings`.`category_id` is not null limit 1
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour ( and how to fix :)???

Tx

Comment: Post your query where you are trying to fetch category and also did you define a relationship in settings model for category?

Comment: nop, I have no relationship in settings model for category. I will update my question with query. please hold on

Comment: try dd the `category` in foreach

Comment: each row is ok  : {"id":2,"name":"Varonil Segunda Fuerza","created_at":"2015-12-25 00:10:48","updated_at":"2015-12-25 00:10:48","pivot":{"tournament_id":1,"category_id":2,"created_at":"2015-12-25 00:33:44","updated_at":"2015-12-25 00:33:44"}}

Comment: Is it an `object` or `array`?

Comment: an object, but he has no hasOne relationship

Comment: As you did not loaded any relationship yet how would it contain that?
Now try `dd($category->settings)` and check out the output

Comment: it loads the CategorySettings Object, but only for the first row

Comment: So if you `dd` the second row what you get? an `object` or `array`?

Comment: Now try my updated answer

Comment: now that I think, it is normal, I just have filled the first one. I think is my mistake, if nothing, I should display defaults values.

Comment: please put it as an answer, you help me a lot resolving this!

Comment: Try my updated answer if it contains settings it will echo other wise it won't throw any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the condition in `if` statement. If it has settings it will echo out other wise it will keep continue

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  @if(count($category->settings) > 0)
   {{ $category->settings->columnname }}
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You didn't read well. the $category->settings is an array, so I can't access column name. I could access $category->settings['columnname], but it is pointing a problem. Then, you are doing exacly what I do. I print {{ $category->settings}} to see what's inside, and only the first row is filled